# Is it possible to authenticate the default and a custom User model parallelly?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-models, django-admin

Our project deems necessary the need for a custom `PublicUser` model. We need to preserve the default authentication for the `/admin/` endpoint as well.

In contrast, we'll have a public `/public/login/` endpoint wherein we'd like to implement the aforementioned custom `PublicUser` model that we can we with the default `authenticate()`, `login()`, and `logout` functions.

So, chronologically, the default `User` model must still work with the `/admin/` endpoint; the `PublicUser` model must work with the `/public/login/` endpoint. And, both the models must work with the default `authentication()`, `login()`, and `logout()` functions so as to manage public sessions with ease.

> Note: We do not want to change the default authentication model for the `/admin/` endpoint. It must be separate.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.PublicUser" # Refrain from doing this
```

Any suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: There is one `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. So you can for example pick the `User`  model, and use a `OneToOneField` from something like a `Profile` to that `User`.

Comment: But, we need to keep the database tables separate.

Comment: Create a new authentication backend?

Comment: @MohitSolanki, thank you for your comment. I ended up implementing a custom AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS rule in settings.py.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, thank you too, for taking the time to help. I appreciate it. :-)